# The size of an initialized array as element of the array (USB descriptor)

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

I want to have a construct similar to this (invalid) one:

```
const uint8_t uArray[] = { uint8_t(sizeof(uArray)), 1, 2, 3 };
```

and the uArray[0] should be 4 and be filled automatically at the compile time, this is the situation for USB descriptors definition that are usually expressed as an array of bytes with the first byte value being the size in elements.

This theoretically should be possible because the array is initialized already but somehow I'm not able to express it.

Any suggestions to solve this are welcomed.

Comment: does it have to be an array? how about an `enum`?

Comment: Where do you get the values from? Are they const values like in the example, or do you get them e.g. from a stream or similar? If they are already stored in a different container, you could derive the size from there. It doesn't answer your question, but might solve the problem.

Comment: "* array is initialized already*" - well, it is not, hence the error saying it's incomplete. You are in the middle of it. Although its size could be derived, it would probably need a little bit more sophisticated parsing logic, i.e. postponing the value computation until the declaration is completed.

Comment: @Kif I think you can make it an answer, it totally makes sense, and you have a quote. I would put under scrutiny of smarter people vote. It makes sense what OP wants is possible, but most probably compiler logic is not that sophisticated, and this is backed by the standard.

Comment: With C++11 you could use a temporary `constexpr` array without the size, then compute the size from that and construct another array with the actual data. The `constexpr` should make sure you do not actually have that temporary array or the copying in the binary.

Comment: Given that the size of your array must match the declared size in the device descriptor header or the protocol will fail I would say that you should use fixed size arrays and then the compiler will raise an error if you make the common mistake of too few or too many initialisers.

Comment: I doesn't have to be an array specifically, just some construct that is translated binary without padding and where I can add elements and have the size calculated at the compile time, enum, struct, whatever it fits.

Comment: Also, if somebody can suggest a pre-processor trick this will do it at well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read the specification http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf, and in paragraph 6.7.8.19 it states that the initialisation happens in initialisation list order, and in 6.7.8.22 it says "If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer. At the end of its initializer list, the array no longer has incomplete type." To me, this suggests that at the time of initialisation of the first value, the type of the array (and its size) are still incomplete.

Comment: Does **"*At the end of its initializer list, the array no longer has incomplete type*"** imply `int a[]={1,2,3,int(sizeof(a))};` is valid?

Comment: No, because the value of the last element needs to be determined before the array is at the end of the initialiser list.

Comment: Well, this means that with the standard compiler implementations (specifically GCC)  this is not possible at all and I have to either count somehow the bytes or do an initialization routine in the program to fill the values ?

Comment: Thanks a lot Kif and others that took your time to answer, it seems that for the moment there is no way to do this at the compile time strictly from the C language, GCC extensions or pre-processor. I will add a build script to parse and change the first element of the descriptor arrays accordingly.